# Error: com.android.volley.server error, al insertar dato en mysql desde android

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio

estoy intentando conectarme con una base de datos mysql externa desde android. La base de datos esta en un servidor externo. En teoria tendria que mandar el parametro "nombre" por `POST` y el archivo "insertar_producto.php" se encargaria de meter el dato en la base de datos. Pero obtengo este error en el toast que he puesto en el metodo `onErrorResponse`:`com.android.volley.server error`. Y en la consola del android compruebo que es un error 500. Este es el archivo insertar_producto.php:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$nombre=$_POST("nombre");
//$nombre="Jose";
$consulta="insert into pruebas value(0,'$nombre')";
mysqli_query($db,$consulta);// or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

y este el codigo del mainActivity del android studio:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText nombre;
    Button boton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nombre=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        boton=findViewById(R.id.button);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarServicio("https://www.arcarsenal.com/insertar_producto.php");
            }
        });
    }
    private void ejecutarServicio(String URL)
    {

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "operacion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })

        {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros= new HashMap<String,String>();
                parametros.put("nombre",nombre.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.getCache().clear();
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

El error parece estar en el envio de los parametros ya que si no recibo ningun parametro en el archivo "insertar_producto.php" es decir, si lo pongo de esta forma:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
//$nombre=$_POST("nombre");
$nombre="Jose";
$consulta="insert into pruebas value(0,'$nombre')";
mysqli_query($db,$consulta);// or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

me inserta perfectamente el nombre "Jose" en la base de datos.

Comment: Los errores 500 son errores de servidor. Esto está mal, y esa puede ser la causa: `$nombre=$_POST("nombre");`  cámbialo por esto: **`$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];`** y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: perfecto!, ha funcionado, gracias.

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta dada como aceptada, de modo que pueda ser útil a futuros usuarios. Me alegro de que se haya resuelto. Considera también las recomendaciones indicadas en la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Los errores 500 son errores de servidor.

Esto está mal, y esa puede ser la causa:

```
$nombre=$_POST("nombre");
```

Cámbialo por esto:

```
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
```

Debería funcionar, salvo otros errores.

Y es que [`$_POST`, como indica el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php), es un array asociativo, y la sintaxis para leer los datos de los arrays asociativos es `$elArray["laClave"]`

### Algunas recomendaciones

- Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas, o podrían causar estragos en tu servidor desde Android.
- A tu código le faltan controles, como capturar posibles errores, verificar que los datos pasados por POST no están vacíos etc, a fin de informar al usuario de esas situaciones. Si no controlas eso, el código se quedará mudo ante esos pequeños fallos lógicos.